# Build error after adding image_picker 0.8.6 dependency in flutter ios project

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build, flutter-image-picker

After adding image_picker 0.8.6 into my pubspec.yaml file i get this error in my terminal and then it fails to run, here are images of the error and my info.plist file[Build error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBqcQ.png)[Build error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKU1a.png)[info.plist file 1]
[info.plist 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuNv3.png)

I edited my info.plist multiple times and even deleted my pubspec.lock file and running again but it failed.

answer: Basically guys the reason i was having this error was cause in my path there was a file with an ' , so be careful naming files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

1.You can change platform ios version,
Go to your ios folder and open pod file then uncomment the platform ios version and change it to 11.

2.Remove the version number of image picker from pubspec.yaml file(It's work for me)

Comment: it didnt work. its still showing the same error